# drupal_add_css, drupal_add_js does not work

Tags: drupal, preprocessor

I am using `drupal_add_css()` and `drupal_add_js()` to add CSS and JavaScript files to my Drupal site. I am doing this in a module called control so the function I'm using is  called `control_preprocess_page(&$vars)`.

But in my theme nothing is added!

Comment: can you add some sample code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason these functions aren't working within the preprocess_page() function is that [template_preprocess_page()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_page/6) (which is called first) has already formatted the structured content into variables $scripts and $styles. If you want to add additional js or css at the preprocess level, you need to regenerate those 2 variables, something like this:

```
function control_preprocess_page(&$vars) {
  // Add new CSS.
  drupal_add_css('path/to/css/foo.css');
  // Rebuild the 'styles variable.
  $vars['styles'] = drupal_get_css();

  // Add new JS.
  drupal_add_js(...);
  $vars['scripts'] = drupal_get_js();
}
```

Using drupal_add_js/drupal_add_css in hook_init, or a more precisely targeted function (eg, an alter hook, or nodeapi hook, if applicable), will avoid having to regenerate those variables.

Answer (score 4):

At the point your CSS/JS is needed, you can call it with drupal_add_css/js. You can also use it in the hook_init(), if your module is used on every page.

Comment: +1: the init hook is useful to globally include JS/CSS.  You can also include upon node loading (in hook_nodeapi), comment altering, form altering, and others.

Answer (score 0):

Some pointers that might help:

1) Place your CSS/JS script in your theme folder.
2) In your node.tpl.php  file use the following:

```
<?php drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('theme', 'INSERT_NAME_OF_THEME') . '/INSERT_NAME_OF_CSS_FILE.css'); ?>
```

3) If you place your CSS in a sub folder, you will need the following code:

4) Refresh the cache at yousite.com/admin/settings/performance

5) Sometimes I find that I have to disable the theme at admin/build/themes and the re-enable it.

Comment: While you could do this, it isn't best practice.