# Drupal 6 - Add Javascript to a single page

Tags: javascript, drupal-6, drupal-theming

When I need to add Java Script to a single Drupal page, I paste the following in my node.tpl.php file:

```
<?php drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('theme', 'INSERT_NAME_OF_THEME') . '/INSERT_NAME_OF_JS_FILE.js'); ?>
```

It works fine, but I have been told it is not [best practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4431133/drupal-add-css-drupal-add-js-does-not-work/4432033#4432033). What would be best practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your phptemplate page, in a preprocess function u should like this:

function controller_preprocess_page(&$vars){
if($vars['node']->nid == "THE_ID_OF_THE_NODE")

$vars['varjs']  = 'js/yourjs.js';
}

and then in your page u can do "  ...srcipt`

Answer (score 0):

Try to add your javascript code via the hook_form_alter

Comment: Could you give an example of what you mean? Thanks!