# Drupal WYSIWYG - Different Editor CSS per Node Type, Page, etc?

Tags: drupal, wysiwyg

Im using Drupal with the WYSIWYG module.

I want the CSS in my editor to be the same as my page, so the colors and fonts, etc all look how they will when the page is saved. I have different CSS for different node types, and on certain pages. How can I import these CSS rules into the editor?

Using normal CSS selectors doesn't work if the html is outside of the iframe used by Wysiwyg. Using '.cke_show_borders' as a selector works, but then I cant load different styles on different node edit pages.

Ive posted this question on the modules page and it doesn't seem there is an inbuilt solution, but has anyone found a work around to this problem? Would there be some javascript way of bringing styles into the iframe from the page outside it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid that the basic answer is, "Unfortunately, not for Drupal at the moment."  In order to truly see the CSS that is varying from page to page, the WYSIWYG system would need to be very, very "smart" and tightly integrated with other parts of the system - such as production of the headers that produce the CSS file links.

I've actually worked on a module to try to achieve some of the functionality you describe here - allowing pages to choose different groups of CSS styles on different prepared stylesheets, where these stylesheets were then re-parsed out for specific use in the WYSIWYG editor.  It was a lot of work, and unfortunately it's not at a point of development where it would be good to share.  The next likely step for Drupal would be to include this type of functionality, instead of auto-magically knowing whatever css you are throwing in your template - simply because the freedom Drupal gives you with templates means that that the "core" has no idea at all really of what you're doing with CSS.  If Drupal were to try to integrate template and editor css in the manner you describe, templating would either be majorly restricted, or a lot more complicated than it is now.

If you use WYSIWYG API, you can designate your own stylesheet for the editor there - unfortunately, it's not dynamic, so you can't calculate the path of the stylesheet based on PHP code.

Comment: OK. I see why its hard for Drupal's WYSIWYG to 'know' what styles to use. However, is there a way of loading different CSS on the edit pages by node type? Or, could I add different div tags around editor on different pages, so I could target the text that way?

Comment: Unfortunately, the editor is inside an iframe, which has its own css, so adding tags around the editor here won't help - this is one of the many "traumas" of trying to use a javascript editor.  If the Wysiwyg module allowed for php programming in the field for the stylesheet, you would be able to use dynamically generated stylesheets ... but this itself would also require quite a lot of programming to make it in any way useful.  My condoleances ... it's a beautiful wish, and would be lovely if we had this, but the answer is: not available yet.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem with ckeditor and managed to solve it using [hook_js_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_js_alter/7) (which is only present in drupal7 for now)

It's not the drupalway to use this hook for this problem, but it works anyway.

Maybe this approach could help you achieve the same result for other editors like tinymce

So, as a result I am altering js settings which are usually loaded through [drupal_add_js](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/drupal_add_js/7)($data, 'setting'). So there is something like `Drupal.settings.wysiwyg.configs.ckeditor.formatfull_html.contentsCss` and I'm adding a new element to it. This is an array of css styles, which ckeditor/wysiwyg loads when inits the editor. This code snippet applies to Full html editor (formatfull_html), you will have to change it or modify to meet your needs.

```
function mymodule_js_alter(&$javascript) {
  // Checking if we're editing a node.
  if (arg(0) == 'node' && arg(2) == 'edit') {
    $nid = arg(1);

    // Loading a node to check it's type. 
    // we may be certain that it's loaded from cache.
    $node = node_load((int) $nid);
    if ($node->type == 'your-node-type') {
      foreach ($javascript['settings']['data'] as &$row) {
        // This will make changes to the proper js-settings record.
        if (isset($row['wysiwyg']['configs']['ckeditor']['formatfull_html']['contentsCss'])) {
          $row['wysiwyg']['configs']['ckeditor']['formatfull_html']['contentsCss'][] = url(drupal_get_path('module','mymodule') . '/wysiwyg-style.css');
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It should be noted that styles of editor's button drop-downs are affected by these styles too.

Edit: I just recently managed to make a more "Drupalway" solution to this problem, but approach is the same.

```
function mymodule_element_info_alter(&$types) {
  $types['text_format']['#pre_render'][] = 'mymodule_pre_render_text_format';
}

function mymodule_pre_render_text_format($element) {
  if ($element['#entity_type'] == 'node' && $element['#bundle'] == "your-node-type" && $element['#type'] == 'textarea') {
    $setting = array();
    $setting['wysiwyg']['configs']['ckeditor']['formatfull_html']['contentsCss'][] =  url( drupal_get_path('module','mymodule') . '/wysiwyg-style.css');
    drupal_add_js($setting , 'setting');
  }
  return $element ;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. In my case I wanted different css per site (it a multisite setup) and your `hook_js_alter` example really helped.

Answer (score 0):

You can define the styles in the WYSIWYG editor (are you using CKeditor or TinyMCE?) to set some custom classes around your text (read in the iframe).
After that you can use the [hook_init()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_init/6) to add load contextual css files through the [drupal_add_css()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/drupal_add_css/6) function.

Comment: Im using CKeditor, but I could switch to another to achieve this.

Comment: If I add custom classes around my editing text, how can I then use them to load different CSS as needed per content type, etc? Thanks

Comment: Just to be sure that i follow you, you are trying to change the style of the content that you are editing with the wysiwyg or when you are viewing content.

Comment: Both. I have different styles when viewing content, and I want these styles to be used when editing. So, when your editing content, you see it how it will look after you save. Thanks

Comment: OK so, to manage the style inside the wysiwyg take a look at that ressource if you are using CKeditor http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2102797/adding-custom-styles-to-ckeditor/2538839#2538839 and about the node take a look at that link to see how to implement the drupal_add_css() function. Imagine to wrap that call with statements to check the page for example. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4431133/drupal-add-css-drupal-add-js-does-not-work/4435462#4435462